# Booting Linux OS from syslinux bootloader

Tags: boot, boot-loader, syslinux

I have a multiboot usb stick in `/dev/sdb`. The `sdb1` partition contains linux distribution images and has `syslinux` installed on it. The second partition `sdb2` has a Linux OS installed on it (Ubuntu).

1) How can I boot this second partition from the first?

On the [Syslinux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux#Chainloading_other_Linux_systems) I read this example code, for the syslinux.cfg file:

```
timeout 10

ui menu.c32

label Other Linux
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux
    initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    append root=/dev/sda3 rw quiet

label MAIN
    com32 chain.c32
    append hd0 0
```

2) How can I specify the root when it is located on my usb stick? The problem I see is that my usb is sometimes mounted on `/dev/sda`, on `/dev/sdb`, or on `/dev/sdc` so it is not fixed at all...

3) Does `hd0` always refer to the computer's first hard drive, or could it be an external hard drive such as an USB stick?

Comment: Is your USB mounted via your `fstab`?

Comment: No it is not. Should it be?

Comment: Yes, If you want that USB stick treted as a stationary device, you need to mountit as if it were one.  You do that via `fstab`, then follow the Arch Wiki, set the boot record etc, test the config by rebooting, tweak, and repeat.

Comment: The file is in `/etc/fstab`. It is part of a linux system right? So if I boot from my usb stick, the first system being not mounted, wont its fstab be useless?

Comment: You miss the point.  You must add the entry in an FSTAB of an already working system, then add syslinux to the USB stick.  By doing it this way you eliminate question 2 and 3 as you can refer syslynux to use the mount point instead of the actual device.

Comment: Does it mean that installing syslinux on my usb stick saves the current working system's `fstab` ? Where?

Comment: Yes you edit and save the working system's fstab, work with syslinux, tweak and install syslinux using the fstab, reboot with the usb stick.  If everything works like you want, you boot back into the working system, remove the fstab entry and reboot the working system.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: *"boot this second partition from the first"* in 1) and *"specify the root"* in 2)?

Comment: I have an usb sick on which I put multiple Linux installation images on a first partition which is already bootable and working with a graphical boot menu. I have a on this usb a second partition on which I want to install a Linux OS. In 1) I mean that I would like to see this OS in the graphical boot menu from the first partition. In 2) I am talking about the `root` argument found in the `APPEND` from the `syslinux.cfg` configuration file.